# What’s the difference between these two options?

Tags: relative-clauses

It is well documented that phrasal verbs,_________, are a considerable source of frustration for many EFL learners, are a common feature of the Scandinavian language.

A. Which consist of a verb and an adverb or proposition

B. Whose verb plus particle structure

Comment: What do you mean by particle structure?

Comment: I have no idea. I think particle means *an adverb or a preposition that can combine with a verb to make a phrasal verb* which I found in the dictionary. But I don’t know what’s the meaning of “particle structure”.

Comment: @user112563: it should be parsed "whose (verb plus particle) structure", which means they consist of a verb and a particle.

Comment: B is not a properly formed relative clause: it does not have a verb. You could say "whose structure **is** verb plus particle".

Comment: @JavaLatte: if you take out the comma after the blank, the relative clause has the verb *are* and you have a nearly grammatical sentence (although *structure* takes the singular verb *is*). On the other hand, if you leave it the comma in, the sentence has two verbs is wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't understand why the sentence with the comma in and two verbs would be grammatically wrong. *It is well documented that phrasal verbs, which have more than one word, are a considerable source of frustration for many EFL learners, are a common feature of the Scandinavian language.* In my opinion, it would be grammatically correct while being long-winded and a bit clunky! *Shrug*

Comment: @cardinal ",are ... , are" does not sound right to me. ", are ... , and are" would be OK.